# Is there a way I can have the aspectj maven plugin ignore missing weave dependencies instead of failing the build?

Tags: maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I wrote an aspect library that auto-instruments traces and because most of the developers using this have multi-module projects, it would be nice if they could just configure the aspectj-maven-plugin for compile-time weaving in the parent pom.xml instead of each module's pom.xml.  The problem is that not all modules require certain weave dependencies and as such I would like it if the plugin could ignore those missing dependencies when weaving those modules instead of failing the build.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure plugin version and common settings in the parent's `pluginManagement` section, then simply add the plugin group ID and name to each module's `plugins` section where it is needed, optionally amending or changing the configuration. Adding a plugin to the parent POM even though not all modules use it, is simply wrong from a Maven perspective.